# Return Column Letter Associated with Match In Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to create a macro to automate the creation of an import sheet into a system.

I need to pull in a date value from a separate workbook that is open, which has multiple tabs. Each tab has the date listed in a different row or column, which will always be somewhere in the range A10:C11.

I basically want to find the column letter that the "Date" falls under so I can iterate over all rows in this column at a later point.

So I try to do this:

```
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook Name.xlsx")
Dim wb2ws As Worksheet
Dim wb2wsrange As Range
Dim wb2wsdatecolnum As Long
Dim wb2wsdatecollet As String

Set wb2ws = wb2.Worksheets("Name of Desired Worksheet in Separate Workbook")
Set wb2wsrange = wb2ws.Range("A10:C11").Find(What:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, 
LookAt:=xlWhole)
wb2wsdatecolnum = wb2wsrange.Column
wb2wsdatecollet = Split(wb2ws.Cells(1, wb2wsdatecolnum).Address, "$")(1)
```

Where I referenced finding the column letter from here:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/vba-code-to-convert-column-number-to-letter-or-letter-to-number

The problem is: wb2wsdatecolnum always returns "1" even if the "Date" value falls in column B or C. I don't know why. This in turn causes wb2wsdatecollet to return "A" even when it should be "B" or "C".

Any thoughts why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised your code runs as is. Where `wb2ws` is a string, it cannot have a Range property `wb2ws.Range(…` should --> error.  Do you have error checking disabled?  Also, the reason you state is not a reason to need a column letter. Just use the column number.

Comment: Your assignment of `wb2ws` doesn't work. You need to declare it as an object `Dim wb2ws As Worksheet` and then assign it properly with a `Set` statement `Set wb2ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheet2 'replace with your desired worksheet`

Comment: Sorry, I was retyping the code and left out the reference where I set wb2ws = wb2.Worksheets where wb2 is the name of my other workbook.

Comment: I've never touched error checking so I don't know how to tell if it's disabled or not.

Comment: Try to `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` `wb2wsrange.Address` to get to the bottom of this. The problem is most likely finding the correct range

Comment: To reiterate a previous comment, there is no need for a column letter. Column numbers work quite well in `Cells` or `Columns` calls. Even better, work with the `Range` object that is the result of `Find` - though test that `Find` is successful first, otherwise the range will be `Nothing`.

Comment: I tried the MsgBox wb2wsrange.Address and it always returns $A$10 - but the "Date" is not always in this cell. It returns this even if the "Date" is in $B$10. Why is this?

Comment: `wb2ws = wb2.Worksheets("Name of Desired Worksheet in Separate Workbook")` should still be returning an error, unless you have error checking turned off. Usually better to copy/paste code, so we can all start with the same data.  Retyping frequently results in transcription errors.

Comment: Why would it return an error? The goal of wb2ws is to indicate what worksheet in another workbook I am working in. I have a larger loop that will change this value based on what sheet I'm currently in.

Comment: I think the issue is somehow caused by the fact that the match value I'm using is "Date". When I use any other string it matches to the correct column. 

When I try to find the column associated with the "Date" string, I always get the first one. Thoughts?

Comment: You have declared it as a `Worksheet`.  It is an object and must be `Set`, else you will get a `91` error.

Comment: OK I added the Set notation. But I think I found the issue: When I use "Date" as my match value I always get "1", but if I use any other string e.g. "SKU" then I get the correct column reference. But "Date" does not always appear in column 1 in each sheet, so I'm really confused by this. I checked and the cells in column 1 are always formatted as "General" - could this be an issue? Like somehow VBA thinks there is a match because General could signify a Date format?? Even though I am searching for a Date string?

Comment: Because your code was not returning an error before you added the `Set` keyword, I suspect there is something else going on either with your data or your code.  And no, `.Find(What:="Date", …` will not be triggered by anything other than "Date" in the cell. You haven't created merged cells, have you?

Comment: No merged cells ):. But I find it really odd that searching for "Date" doesn't work while searching for any other string produces the correct results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201964/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-kamui).

Answer (score 0):

`Find` returns a `Range` including the cells where "Date" is found. So it will return one cell (A3 or D6).

`Application.Match` seem more appropriate to your need.

Comment: I tried: wb2wsdatecolnum = Application.Match("Date", wb2ws.Range("A10:C11"), 0), but I get an empty result even though "Date" is in the range I specified. :(

Comment: `Dim wb2wsdatecolnum As Double`